# configure position dilogbox in yii

Tags: php, yii, dialog, widget, position

i used dialogbox in yii I want to change postinion to near link dialog how can it?

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialogg',
        'width'=>200,
        'height'=>100,


        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));
    echo 'dialog content here';
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>

<?php echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('ui','Dialogooooooooo'), '#', array('onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

You can try this to change the position of your dialog:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
  ....
      'position'=>array('my'=>'bottom','at'=>'bottom', 'of' => '#targetLink),
      // or 'position'=>array(x, y), 
  ....
    ),
));

.....
<?php echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('ui','Dialogooooooooo'), '#', array('id' => 'targetLink', 'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;')); ?>
```

You can see this link http://api.jqueryui.com/position/ to know what 'my', 'at' and 'of' are working. BTW, I updated my example: specify value for `'of' option` and `id` for the `link`.

More info: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: excuse me what is my or at? i change this value by bottom or top and left or right or center but i have not any change

Comment: @maryam: I updated my answer, please have a look at it!

Comment: @maryam: Did you find out?